# Routing to webdev serve in AngularDart

Tags: angular-dart

I have an AngularDart site in a docker container, with a Nginx routing in front like: `http://<ip>/site`. I can attach to the container and start `webdev serve`.

But when I `curl http://<ip>/site` 
I get:

```
Could not find web/site/index.html or any files in web/site
```

In my attempt to solve this I am looking at the following description:

In [this](https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/router/1) routing description:

```
<script>
  // WARNING: DO NOT set the <base href> like this in production!
  // Details: https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/router
  (function () {
    var m = document.location.pathname.match(/^(\/[-\w]+)+\/web($|\/)/);
    document.write('<base href="' + (m ? m[0] : '/') + '" />');
  }());
</script>
```

Update: If I fix set:

```
document.write('<base href="/site/"/>');
```

It works with an error in the browser unable to find main.js - but it still works.

Do you know how to fix the routing problem og maybe just what is the `/web($|\/)/` doing?

Comment: Is this for production or development?

Comment: It is for development. If production I think we should set a fixed/constant ref in  <base href=/site/.

Comment: It must be something with the routing as it works if I run it on localhost. I just need to run in container as it connect to other containers on kubernetes.